# Sublime Text 3: Keybind/Shortcut for "Permute Selections > Sort"?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, sublime-text-3, key-binding

Is there some way to add a keybind for the following menu command?

> Edit > Permute Selections > Sort

Also, if there is a comprehensive list defining how to properly reference all of the ST3 menu commands in order to bind a shortcut for them, please let me know. I've been trying to find information like this for more than one menu command, but my Googling efforts have mostly proven unsuccessful thus far.

Answer (score 0):

I found something online that helped figure this out.

> You can enter sublime.log_commands(True) in the console to see
>   everything that Sublime is doing.

Source:
https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/comprehensive-key-bindings-list/5302/2

Here's the keybind I set up for this in ST3:

```
    { "keys": ["shift+f9"], "command": "sort_selection", "args": {"case_sensitive": false} },
```